# Client certificate per endpoint

Tags: azure-api-management

I would like to configure a self signed client certificate for a certain endpoint.

I uploaded the PFX, copied the thumbprint and added the following line under `<base/>` in the "Inbound processing" section:

```
 <policies>
   <inbound>
      <base />
      <authentication-certificate thumbprint="THUMBPRINT" />
   </inbound>
   <backend>
      <base />
   </backend>
   <outbound>
      <base />
   </outbound>
   <on-error>
      <base />
   </on-error>
</policies>
```

If I go to the browser and access the endpoint I see that the site wide SSL cert is being used and not the self signed cert for that specific endpoint.

I tried adding it under "proxy" in custom domains section but it's being by overridden by the SSL certificate in the App Service of the domain in the "Web service URL" for the API.

Any ideas?

Comment: there is too much missing in your question to be able to give any sort of an answer. Could you add more detail to a question? Like how your setup looks, which endpoints you call, how you call them e.t.c. Right now its really unclear what are you trying to do since "return a certificate" can mean quite anything.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin I have REST API hosted as an App Service. I have the gateway that stands between the API and the calling client. I would like to return a self signed SSL certificate for one endpoint (called using REST) and have the default SSL certificate of App Service returned for other endpoints. To answer your question, I don't think the name matters but lets call it /messages/get needs to return the self signed cert and the rest need to return the App Service cert

Comment: It seems like adding the authentication-certificate to the outbound might work but I'm unable to add it.

Answer (score 0):

authentication-certificate is a policy that allows APIM to use certificate to authenticate to backend service, not to client's calling APIM. Since you're testing in browser I assume that you want to setup custom domain with custom certificate, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain

Comment: cool thanks! I'll take a look. What's the difference between the "authentication-certificate" in "Inbound Processing" and "Backend"?

Comment: Also per the document linked, I uploaded the SSL cert in the "proxy" section but it's being overriden by the SSL cert in SSL Settings in the App Service

Comment: authentication-certificate - is a policy that applies client certificate to the ongoing request. Inbound, outbound, backend - policy document sections. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-policies

Not sure what problems exactly you have with SSL cert. Perhaps update question with more detail?

Comment: You are configuring self signed SSL certificate for APIM proxy. But later you referring to SSL certificate in app service/website! Are you trying to change certificate of your backend from APIM

Comment: @JJ I want to return a self signed SSL cert for a specific endpoint. The SSL certificate returned however is the SSL cert installed on the app service and not the one on the APIM proxy. How do I return the SSL cert on the APIM proxy?